# multiple wordpress instances routing to different domains, in the same folder laravel folder

Tags: laravel, wordpress, .htaccess

I'm going to try stating my problem as clearly as possible.
I have a laravel app, managing multiple domains as example:
domain1

domain2

domain3

All 3 pointing in the same folder.
I have the domains loading different htmls, with same routes(for example / or /home or /pricing) via grouping domains in Laravel.

however my issue is with wordprss.
If I add in public folder the /blog folder with wordpress I can load domain1.com/blog just fine
however, in domain 2, I can't have blog2/redirecting to same domain2.com/blog

how can I have different wordpress naming and only be accesible by each domain via the same route? (my guess is that is something related to either wordpress config, either htaccess for blocking routes for each domain with different url addresses.

I want to achieve the following:
domain1/blog
domain2/blog
domain3/blog
where source is

domain1/blog1
domain2/blog2
domain3/blog3

and I also want that domain1/blog/pricing
would not be accessible to domain2/blog/pricing if the sources are different. I want 3 different websites folders, pointing to 3 different URL's

Comment: So you have a WP multisite, or what exactly?

Comment: And what exactly is the connection to Laravel here now? Are you using Laravel to somehow serve the WP content?

Comment: I am using laravel, for managing access for each domain. 
for example all 3 domains are pointing to the same folder. 
and in order to load different content, I use laravel for grouping routs. 
in the public folder I want to manage multiple wordpress instances. 
example blog1 to point to blog on domain1, blog2 to point to blog on domain2

Comment: @CBroe I am trying to achieve multiple instances of wordpress, all on the same folder for different domains. 
the goal is to have one laravel app, managing multiple domains, and have multiple wordpress instances

Comment: I can only see that making sense, if by _"multiple instances"_ you actually mean _one_ WordPress system, that has multiple _sites_ in it. I don't know if that will already work, if you set up each site with the specific domain as its base URL; if not, you might have to hook in at some early stage, and use `switch_to_blog` to switch to the correct blog based on the requested host name.

Comment: how can I achieve that? @CBroe

Comment: I am still not sure how this is supposed to integrate with your laravel. If you let anything below `domain1/blog` get handled by WordPress - then how do you expect  `domain1/blog/pricing` to work again using laravel?

Comment: I don't have any route for the wordpress app in laravel. so the route is free and available for wp to use

Answer (score 0):

I finally achieved managing multiple domains, through Laravel domain grouping and Wordpress multisite, by all domains pointing in the sameplace in cpanel.